# Characteristic method to $u_t+au_x-u^2=1$

Tags: analysis, partial-differential-equations, characteristics

Consider the following hyperbolic equation for $u=u(t,x)$, $a\in\mathbb{R}$
$$ \frac{\partial u }{\partial t} + a\frac{\partial u }{\partial x} -u^2 = 1.  $$
I want to show that there is no global solution, that is, *there exists a $t_*$ such that the solution $u$ goes to infinity as $t\rightarrow t_*$*. In order to do that I am thinking in showing that any two characteristic cruves intersec each other. **My problem is to calculate the characteristic curves of the considered equation**. Any help or idea is welcome!

Thank you.

Comment: The method of characteristics gives the caracteristic curves $$x-at=c_1$$ $$\tan^{-1}(u)-t=c_2$$ and solutions of the PDE $$u(x,t)=\tan\big(t+F(x-at)\big)$$where $F$ is an arbitrary function.